# what to do when your sprite sheet gets too big?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-sheet, ccspritebatchnode

I just filled up the sprite sheet for my game, so that I had to increase the max width from 2048 to 4096.  Now the sprite sheet won't load on my iphone 4, although it loads fine on my iphone 5, leading me to think it's either a hardware issue or an iOS version issue as the 4 is still on iOS 5.1.

What can I do in this situation?  I have included the background for my game in the sprite sheet, and that's taking up most of the space.  Should I remove it from the sprite sheet and add it as its own file?  Am I better off starting a second sprite sheet?  What's the best solution in terms of performance?  Is there a way to get a larger sprite sheet to work on older devices?

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware limitation. Solution? Use more than one spritesheet.

Comment: @JamesMorrison Btw, if you, for some reason, target older devices than the iPhone 3GS, you have to use spritesheets with a maximum solution of 1024x1024 for them.

Answer (score 0):

If I was looking to trim the size of my sprite sheet I would remove the background images from the sprite sheet.